# Does BufferedReader block when reading a file?

Tags: java, io, block

I want to use "BufferedReader" to read a live log file, and print new added content to console:

```
File logfile = new File("logFile.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(logfile)));
while(true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
}
```

It will print new added lines, and sometimes will print `null` (means there is no new lines appended to log).

My question is if `reader.readLine()` will be blocked at some conditions? In my test, it doesn't block but I'm not sure if it always be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is if `reader.readLine()` will be blocked at some conditions?

If the file you are reading from is a regular file in the local file system, it is unlikely to block for an appreciable length of time.  In fact, it is only likely to block at all if it has to wait for data to be read from disc.  Block times are likely to be in the order of 10's of milliseconds.

If the file is a remotely mounted file system, then you can get significant delays.  Indeed, under some circumstances the delays could be for an indefinite length of time; e.g. with a remote NFS mount after the remote server has been restarted (depending on the mount options ...).

If the file is a "special file" of some kind (e.g. a tape drive) then significant delays are also possible.  (Socket and pipe streams will also block, though that's not relevant to your example code.)

---

Under normal circumstances, it would be difficult to cause a read to block reliably in a test case.

---

It seems that you are trying to implement a class or method that continually reads lines that are a written to the end of a log file.  There are existing classes to do that; e.g. the Apache commons [`Tailer`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) class.  I recommend you reuse `Tailer` or something similar rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it blocks, but not for appreciable time intervals unless say you are reading from a network drive and something odd happens to the network. A pipe with a dynamic producer is another example.

> In my test, it doesn't block

It doesn't block at EOF, which is possibly what you actually want to know. How could it?

> will print null (means there is no new lines appended to log)

It means you have attempted to read past EOF.

Systems that read their own log files have a very bad smell to me. If you have a need for the system to communicate with itself, *implement* it.

Comment: It's not necessarily his logfile. It could be the file from another system.

Comment: And I know it's probably not his problem, but it would block if logfile was a named pipe or similar.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell Systems that read other system's log files ditto. There are databases and any number of IPC systems for this purpose.

Comment: Unless it is an application which reads other logfiles like logstash. That is definitely not a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading from a blocking `FileInputStream`, the execution will block for short spans of time while the operating system reads data from permanent storage. Even if the file is stored on a local disk, the disk has to be rotated and the read-head has to be moved to the right position, which takes time since both are physical objects, and during that time your program does nothing but wait.

The `readLine` method returns `null` when it reaches the end of the file. When that happens what you'll want to do is wait for the file to be updated and then try to read more:

```
while(true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Actually this is not perfect either because if the last line of the log file is incomplete `readLine` returns it, and when the external process writes the rest of the line you will get it with a separate call to `readLine`. Net effect: some lines may be split in the output.